# Building a generic display function for computations results

Tags: python, displayobject

I a quite new to python and to the scientific computation world.

As a beginning, I am building a module containing definitions of usual mathematical functions with power series.

As an example, here is the code for the exponential function :

```
def exponential(x):
"""Exponential function"""
exp=1.0
term=1.0
iteration=1
factorial=1
while(abs(term/factorial)>1e-15):
    factorial*=iteration
    term*=x
    exp+=term/factorial
    iteration+=1
return exp
```

Next, I want to display computation results from that function in a nice table such as the following :

```
### Evaluations for the exponential function ###

x=-4.00  --- exp(-4.00)=0.018315638888734     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=-3.50  --- exp(-3.50)=0.030197383422319     --- precision=0.000000000000001
x=-3.00  --- exp(-3.00)=0.049787068367864     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=-2.50  --- exp(-2.50)=0.082084998623899     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=-2.00  --- exp(-2.00)=0.135335283236613     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=-1.50  --- exp(-1.50)=0.223130160148430     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=-1.00  --- exp(-1.00)=0.367879441171442     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=-0.50  --- exp(-0.50)=0.606530659712633     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=+0.00  --- exp(+0.00)=1.000000000000000     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=+0.50  --- exp(+0.50)=1.648721270700128     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=+1.00  --- exp(+1.00)=2.718281828459046     --- precision=0.000000000000000
x=+1.50  --- exp(+1.50)=4.481689070338066     --- precision=0.000000000000002
x=+2.00  --- exp(+2.00)=7.389056098930649     --- precision=0.000000000000002
x=+2.50  --- exp(+2.50)=12.182493960703471    --- precision=0.000000000000002
x=+3.00  --- exp(+3.00)=20.085536923187661    --- precision=0.000000000000007
x=+3.50  --- exp(+3.50)=33.115451958692326    --- precision=0.000000000000014
x=+4.00  --- exp(+4.00)=54.598150033144265    --- precision=0.000000000000028
```

This table is generated by the code below :

```
from math import exp
start=-4.0
end=4.0
step=0.5
spacesx0=(1+len(str(int(end))))
spaces0=(1+len(str(int(exp(abs(end))))))

print("### Evaluations for the exponential function ###")
print("")

for i in range(int(start/step),int(end/step)+1):

    # computations
    x=step*i
    expx=exponential(x)
    precision=abs(expx-exp(x))

    # spaces calculations
    spacesx=spacesx0+1-(len(str(int(abs(x)))))
    spaces=spaces0+1-(len(str(int(expx))))+spacesx

    # text formating
    if x<0:
        s="x=%.2f"+" "*spacesx+"--- exp(%.2f)=%.15f"+" "*spaces+"--- precision=%.15f"
    else:
        s="x=+%.2f"+" "*spacesx+"--- exp(+%.2f)=%.15f"+" "*spaces+"--- precision=%.15f"
    # end text formating

    # display
    print(s % (x,x,expx,precision ))
```

As I want to compute and display results for several other usual functions (cosh, sinh, sin, cos, arctan, ...), I woud like to design a generic display function.

For such a display function, I will need parameters such as a function (which values are actually computed), a title, a x-start,a x-end, and a step, I think.

I also want to add a precision value for the computations.

I am looking forward any advice that can help me design that display function.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to improve what you have is to create a simpler function for displaying any kind of table. You build all your data into cols formatted as you currently have and then pass all of the values to a function. This can then calculate the largest entry in each column, and format the data accordingly:

```
def col_display(data):
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])

    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(col)) for index, col in enumerate(row)]

    for row in data:
        print("  ".join(["%-*s" % (widths[index], col) for index, col in enumerate(row)]))

start=-4.0
end=4.0
step=0.5
spacesx0=(1+len(str(int(end))))
spaces0=(1+len(str(int(exp(abs(end))))))

print("### Evaluations for the exponential function ###")
print("")

output = []
for i in range(int(start/step),int(end/step)+1):

    # computations
    x=step*i
    expx=exponential(x)
    precision=abs(expx-exp(x))

    # text formatting
    if x<0:
        output.append(["x=%.2f" % x, "--- exp(%.2f)=%.15f" % (x,expx), "--- precision=%.15f" % precision])
    else:
        output.append(["x=+%.2f" % x, "--- exp(+%.2f)=%.15f" % (x,expx), "--- precision=%.15f" % precision])

    # end text formatting

col_display(output)
```

This approach would at least remove the need to add spaces, and would make the display as compact as possible:

```
x=-4.00  --- exp(-4.00)=0.018315638888734   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=-3.50  --- exp(-3.50)=0.030197383422319   --- precision=0.000000000000001  
x=-3.00  --- exp(-3.00)=0.049787068367864   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=-2.50  --- exp(-2.50)=0.082084998623899   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=-2.00  --- exp(-2.00)=0.135335283236613   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=-1.50  --- exp(-1.50)=0.223130160148430   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=-1.00  --- exp(-1.00)=0.367879441171442   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=-0.50  --- exp(-0.50)=0.606530659712633   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=+0.00  --- exp(+0.00)=1.000000000000000   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=+0.50  --- exp(+0.50)=1.648721270700128   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=+1.00  --- exp(+1.00)=2.718281828459046   --- precision=0.000000000000000  
x=+1.50  --- exp(+1.50)=4.481689070338066   --- precision=0.000000000000002  
x=+2.00  --- exp(+2.00)=7.389056098930649   --- precision=0.000000000000002  
x=+2.50  --- exp(+2.50)=12.182493960703471  --- precision=0.000000000000002  
x=+3.00  --- exp(+3.00)=20.085536923187661  --- precision=0.000000000000007  
x=+3.50  --- exp(+3.50)=33.115451958692326  --- precision=0.000000000000014  
x=+4.00  --- exp(+4.00)=54.598150033144265  --- precision=0.000000000000028
```